# Export multiple images from image column

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure, how could I modify it to export multiple images at once? A `TicketID` can contain several images, could the `IN` statement work here? Appreciate all answers!

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ExportImage (
 @ImgName NVARCHAR (100)
,@ImageFolderPath NVARCHAR(1000)
,@Filename NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @ImageData VARBINARY (max);
   DECLARE @Path2OutFile NVARCHAR (2000);
   DECLARE @Obj INT

   SET NOCOUNT ON

   SELECT @ImageData = (
     SELECT convert (VARBINARY (max), ImgData, 1)
     FROM Images
     WHERE TicketID = @ImgName
     );

   SET @Path2OutFile = CONCAT (
     @ImageFolderPath
     ,'\'
     , @Filename
     );
 BEGIN TRY
 EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream' ,@Obj OUTPUT;
 EXEC sp_OASetProperty @Obj ,'Type',1;
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Open';
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Write', NULL, @ImageData;
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'SaveToFile', NULL, @Path2OutFile, 2;
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Close';
 EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj;
END CATCH

SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

This is the query I execute:
`exec dbo.ExportImage '2042','C:\ExpImg','2042.jpg'`

Errormsg:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ExportImage (
 @ImgName NVARCHAR (100)
,@ImageFolderPath NVARCHAR(1000)
,@Filename NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @ImageData VARBINARY (max);
   DECLARE @Path2OutFile NVARCHAR (2000);
   DECLARE @Obj INT

   SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @cursor CURSOR
SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT convert (VARBINARY (max), ImgData, 1)
     FROM Images
     WHERE TicketID = @ImgName
OPEN @cursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @cursor INTO @ImageData
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SET @Path2OutFile = CONCAT (
     @ImageFolderPath
     ,'\'
     , @Filename
     );
 BEGIN TRY
 EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream' ,@Obj OUTPUT;
 EXEC sp_OASetProperty @Obj ,'Type',1;
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Open';
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Write', NULL, @ImageData;
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'SaveToFile', NULL, @Path2OutFile, 2;
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Close';
 EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj;
END CATCH

FETCH NEXT
FROM @cursor INTO @ImageData
END
CLOSE @cursor
DEALLOCATE @cursor

END
```

Comment: If I run this I still only get one image exported --exec dbo.ExportImage '2042','C:\ExpImage,'testexport.jpg'                                                                         Do I need to modify this?

Comment: Now you do not have error. I think that the reason why do you get only 1 image is that you overriding the same image several times as you always to the same @ImageFolderPath\@FileName